# how to handle mousedoublick click in better way?

Tags: wpf, listview, event-handling, mouseevent

I have nested `ListView` in wpf.  The user can double click the list item and open the item document.
So, I have `ListView1_MouseDoubleClick` and child listview2  `ListView2_MouseDoubleClick`.

But, when the user double clicks the  listview2 item , the listview1 also receives the `MouseDoubleClick` event.

So... in order to fix this problem as far as I know there are two solutions:

A) Add a bool flag and set to false

```
code:
Listview2_mousedoubleclick()
{
    flag=true;
}

ListView1_mousedoubleclick()
{
    if (flag==true) { flag=false;return}
}
```

B) Use `VisualTreeHelper` and analyze `e.Source` to find which one should respond...

Question: Which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing a routed event bubbling up the control tree here. You may set a `Handled` property in the event itself when you handle it to stop it from bubbling further up. I don't know the exact specifics right now as my WPF knowledge is a bit rusty but there was a way to stop such an event handling chain at a certain point you control.

Comment: Yes! my just want to stop event handing chain. 
I have try e.Handled = true; but the ListView1 still able to receive mouse click event..


//REF: private void ListView2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)